# Variable doesn't change when being set from a function

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to change a member variable from inside a class method:

The class declaration is:

```
class BypassButton{

    public:
        BypassButton();
        BypassButton(double x, double y);

        //methods
        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();
        double getX();
        double getY();
        void toggle();

        bool bypassed;
        double x, y, radius;

};
```

the variable is set in the h file like so:

```
bool bypassed;
```

and then set in the constructor like so:

```
BypassButton::BypassButton(double x, double y){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    bypassed = false;
}
```

Then, I created a function that toggles this variable:

```
void BypassButton::toggle(){
   bypassed = !bypassed;
}
```

When I check the value of the variable inside the function before and after I change it, it seems like everything is OK.

But, when I check the value outside the function, it never changes. I tried using `this->` but it doesn't work.

This is all part of a Pedal Board, so I have a class Pedal that has a BypassButton instance.
Then, I create a vector of Pedal Boards inside of my main class, and call toggle like so:

```
void ofApp::mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button){
    for(int i = 0; i < numPedals; i++){
        BypassButton bb = pedals.at(i).getBypassButton();
        if(x > (bb.x - bb.radius) && x < (bb.x + bb.radius) && y > (bb.y - bb.radius) && y < (bb.y + bb.radius)){
            bb.toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, as usual.

Comment: Can you post the class declaration (or the important bits of it)?

Comment: Looks fine to me. It should behave correctly as you have it written. Can you show the function where you actually use `toggle()`?

Comment: You're doing something wrong in the code you haven't shown here.

Comment: Please post a complete test case, showing how you create the object, call the function, and check the value. The code you've posted looks fine, assuming that's the constructor you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BypassButton bb = pedals.at(i).getBypassButton();
```

This creates a copy of the button stored in `pedals`. You're modifying the copy, not the original. Use a reference instead:

```
BypassButton & bb = pedals.at(i).getBypassButton();
```

making sure that `getBypassButton()` returns a reference.

It might also be appropriate to forbid copying the class to prevent mistakes like this. You can do that by deleting the copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
BypassButton(BypassButton const &) = delete;
void operator=(BypassButton) = delete;
```

Comment: Also, `getBypassButton` needs to return a reference.

Comment: @interjay: Thanks, I didn't spot that.

Answer (score -1):

One possible flaw: Initialize your variable in the first line. When you write it as it is, it will be given an indeterministic value. Can be either true or false.

are you sure  you have called the constructor above ?